# Making the console window bigger in C

Tags: c, windows, console, window, maximize

How can I resize the Windows console window in C?

Comment: C just specifies file i/o. Consoles are OS-specific.

Comment: You need to use `SetConsoleScreenBufferSize` and then `SetConsoleWindowInfo`.  If you can't get this to work, post the code.

Comment: Comment formatting is weird, so I'm just going to edit my post. 

New stuff in response to @HarryJohnston is up there.

Comment: @MichaelAnthonyLeber: generally speaking, anything the original poster wants to add to the question in response to a comment should indeed be made by editing the original post. :-)

Comment: @MichaelAnthonyLeber on Windows to change console window we were using registry entry HKCU\Console

Comment: Yep, you've changed the size of the underlying screen buffer, which makes it possible for the user to resize the window.  Now that you've done that, you should be able to use `SetConsoleWindowInfo` to set the window size to match that of the buffer.

Comment: @QWR: I think that would be to set the default size for all new console windows?  Probably not appropriate for an application that other people are going to use - it's not nice to change someone else's global settings for them.

Comment: @HarryJohnston no , on windows you can change for specific program too

Comment: @QWR: oh, you mean when the console is created automatically by double-clicking the specific program executable.  Fair enough.  But doesn't that mean the console doesn't size itself properly the first time the program runs, since it hasn't had a chance to set the registry yet?

Comment: @HarryJohnston well do it inside setup . )) .

Comment: @QWR: in that case, it doesn't work if the user running it isn't the user that ran setup. :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston I added another edit with stuff about 'SetConsoleWindowInfo'.

Comment: If `coord.X` and `coord.Y` are supposed to be the size (in characters) of the screen, then you should be nearly there.  Just set `SMALL_RECT.Left` and `SMALL_RECT.Top` to zero.  At the moment you're asking for a zero-by-zero window.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Another edit.

Comment: You might need to check the return values and call `GetLastError` to see what error code is being returned.  Your new edit passes `ok` as the second parameter; is this set to `TRUE`?  The second parameter needs to be `TRUE`.  You could also call `GetLargestConsoleWindowSize` (after resizing the buffer) to make sure you're not exceeding the maximum size.

Comment: @HarryJohnston When I put GetLastError after the SetConsoleWindowInfo function, I got 87. I changed the second parameter back to TRUE, I thought since ok was  bool value, that it would work, but I'll check it later. Maximum Window Size I got was (240,98) but that shouldn't be an issue anyways, because coord.X and coord.Y are the same values that I had for SetConsoleScreenBufferSize.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I looked up the error code for 87, and it says invalid parameter...which I guess should definitely be the third one for the SMALL_RECT test struct right?

So what am I doing wrong at this point?

Comment: I'd missed the out-by-one error.  Try `test.Right = coord.X - 1` and `test.Bottom = coord.Y - 1`.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yup that fixed it! 

God thats complicated just for doing that, but thank you it finally worked.

Comment: Since you've got it working, it would be preferable if you would post the working code as an answer.

Comment: Of course, will do. 

And I tried the "ok" as a parameter for the second bool value (instead of TRUE) and it works.

Comment: Tooooo many edits. You should condense them into a single question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, after much deliberation, I got the code working.

Using this include:

```
#include <windows.h>
```

This struct:

```
struct SMALL_RECT {
    SHORT Left;
    SHORT Top;
    SHORT Right;
    SHORT Bottom;
};
```

And this function:

```
void adjustWindowSize()
{
    struct SMALL_RECT test; 

    HANDLE hStdout;
    COORD coord;
    BOOL ok;

    hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    coord.X = 100;
    coord.Y = 50;
    ok = SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(hStdout, coord);

    test.Left = 0;
    test.Top = 0;
    test.Right = coord.X-1;
    test.Bottom = coord.Y-1;

    SetConsoleWindowInfo(hStdout, ok, &test);

} //end adjustWindowSize
```

I successfully adjusted the size of the console window to the values in coord.X and coord.Y

Comment: While this probably works, it makes no sense to pass the return value of `SetConsoleScreenBufferSize` as the `bAbsolute` parameter of `SetConsoleWindowInfo`.

Comment: I'm unable to get this to work..   I'm on Window 11, using VS 2019 in C mode. 
 SetConsoleScreenBufferSize always returns false.   SetConsoleWindowInfo only returns true if test.Left and test.Top = 0.   However, it never resizes the console window, no matter what I put in Right and Bottom.