# SetConsoleInfo window resizing doesn't work c++

Tags: c++, winapi, console

I am trying to make an automatic windows CMD function
There is my code:

```
short x = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
short y = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
SMALL_RECT rect = {0,0, x, y};
SetConsoleWindowInfo(hConsole, TRUE, &rect);
```

For some reason window resizing doesn't work.  I checked GetSystemMetrics, and it's working fine. Please help.

Comment: You *do* know that the sizes you get from `GetSystemMetrics` is in *pixels* and the sizes you pass to `SetConsoleWindowInfo` is in *characters* (i.e. rows and columns)?

Comment: oops, sorry about that, how can I convert from pixels to rows and characters, I don't know how many pixels wide a character is or a row. Can you please show me how?

Comment: `GetConsoleFontSize` will give you the font size, then just divide the pixel res by it.

Comment: For me it looks like GetConsoleFont returns a value too high, it srill doesn't work :/

Comment: Well, that's not going anywhere.  Why don't you just leave it up to the user, he'll know how to maximize a window.  This kind of all-your-desktop-belong-to-me programming is pretty hostile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use system("MODE 650") in roder to make the console screen fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set both the buffer size and the window size. You are only doing the latter. You'll need a call to `SetConsoleScreenBufferSize` as well. This answer shows you how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17163497/505088