# Setting a console window specific size at application launch

Tags: c++, windows, console-application, window-resize

I'm using windows 10 and the console is being created in visual studio 2015.
It is being created simply as a win32 console application in c plus plus.

I created a videoMemory simulator for a console application in c++.

```
class VideoSim
{
private:
char video[MAX_ROWS * MAX_COLS]; // row is 29, columns  is 80
int currentRow;
int currentColumn;
```

I display a memory block in the console window that displays 29 rows across and 80 columns down holding 2,320 different locations that I can print out. This application will ask me a question create a little image next to my answer.

When I run this application, my console window stretches further then 80 columns  across. How can I have it defaulted so the console is at a set size, therefor the space I see can only technically all be written to.

I am not familiar with any console specific functions, if someone could kindly just point me in the right direction.

as far as printing out to my video sim, I set the cursor location

```
void VideoSim::SetCursorPosition(int r, int c)
{
    if (c > MAX_COLS || r > MAX_ROWS)
{
    printf("OUTSIDE OF RANGE                  --\n");
    printf("Max column = 40, Max row = 10     --\n\n");
}
currentColumn = c;
currentRow = r;
}
```

then I print at that location, hence always staying within the virtual video memory range.

Comment: What OS? How are you creating your console? How are you producing output?

Comment: @KenWhite I edited for you

Comment: You didn't *edit for me*. You edited to provide necessary details to your question. Your edit is also incomplete; *created simply as a win32 console application in c plus plus* is meaningless.  *c plus plus* is  not a language, and *created simply* conveys no meaning. What kind of *console application*? Are you using the console functions (like `CreateConsole`) or some other means? This is a technical site, and we expect **specific** questions. A vague *I have this thing, and I want it to do something* is not acceptable here. If you want help, provide the necessary details.

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience, let me rephrase my question.

Comment: @KenWhite I hope this is closer to be within the standards.

Comment: Vast improvement. :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Window's console window API to resize the window, but, the simplest is to just use a C++ library `system` call with a `mode con ...` command.

Comment: You are being downvoted because your answer is incorrect. User programs should not resize the console window. If a user program needs a console window of a specific size, it should be a GUI process that creates and links to its own console window (more complicated than OP would like) or use a shortcut link to initialize a console window. Further, you are suggesting doing things the wrong way.

Comment: actually, in all honestly, this is what I would like. I did some more digging and I do want the window to be automatically adjusted. Bare with me, it may not be up to policy standards as @Dúthomhas would say, but it's something neat I want to try and do. Let me be creative

Comment: @Robolisk: Just post a new question if you run into problems. This was a minimum answer to get you going. In particular the `mode con...` only adjusts the text buffer size, but that's what you want to get your program going. Doing this at the API level is intricate because the buffer size can't be adjusted to less than the window, and the window can't be adjusted to larger than the buffer. So it's a 3-step process at the API level. But with the buffer already large enough via a `mode con...`, I think if desired you can just adjust the window via the API, without the roundabout mutual fixups.

Comment: You may find this useful: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160553/making-the-console-window-bigger-in-c). The presented code is absolutely not perfect but it shows how to call the functions.

Answer (score 1):

You're actually going about it the wrong way.

While your application technically could modify the console, *it should not*.
It is the user's prerogative to do that. So... as the user, you should:

**Create a shortcut that starts your program with the desired console.**

This is actually rather easy. Right-click your app and modify the startup parameters, including console size and, if you wish, position.

Thereafter, link everything that triggers your application to the *shortcut*, which will set-up your console window and start your application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the application will only be used by me, its a fun thing I'm creating that will help me count how money I'm wasting on smoking. 

I was going to create it so the application can also auto start on a usb key or computer start up, so I'd prefer it to be automatic.

Comment: That's fine. Link your automatic processes to the shortcut link and enjoy.

Comment: I would still like to know if there is a way to default the console windows within the application.

Comment: @Robolisk: re "I would still like to know", why then did you select this answer as solution, and not mine. After all, this does not answer your question or solve your problem. While mine did.

Comment: @Robolisk Yes, the way is to detach from any current console or start as a GUI, then create and attach to a new console which you can size yourself. This is a bit of work to do properly, especially for a beginner.

If you are asking about the Windows Console in general, you can adjust and size it using the window menu (click the titlebar icon) and apply changes to all future consoles. It does not help your specific problem; your program requires fixed (not user-defined) dimensions. Thus the shortcut to initialize a properly-sized console for your application before launching your application.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf "does not answer your question or solve your problem" -- according to what fantasy logic? It is exactly the correct answer to prepare and size the console according to the needs of the program. It is exactly the wrong answer to modify the console given to the program; program does not have that moral right to modify user's consoles.

Comment: @Dúthomhas: re " program does not have that moral right to modify user's consoles", what planet are you from?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I'm from a very old planet that understands something about UI design and text terminals. But, since we've degenerated into personal attacks, I will consider this conversation over.

Comment: @Dúthomhas: It's not a "discussion"; what you responded to was not addressed to you; and you have not answered what was asked for, instead proffering silly advice that is pretty user-hostile.

Comment: I understand standards and code of practice, which in a more standardized setting I would abide by these ethics, but for my own personal sake I believe breaking them would be quite the adventure.